# SetOnPreferenceClickListener Issue

Tags: android, preference

[a busy cat http://dl.dropbox.com/u/36109322/Custom.JPG](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/36109322/Custom.JPG)

Hi all,
Does anyone know how to solve this issue ? It is a proper coding but why it shows this error? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you don't have the `Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener` package imported.

Change `new onPreferenceClickListener()` to `new Preference.onPreferenceClickListener()`

Since you're using Eclipse, you can also hover over `onPreferenceClickListener()` and choose to import it.